Mobile connect transactional messages - keyword optin bypass
We only use mobile connect for transactional messaging and not marketing.
Is there a way to disable the requirement of mobile optin in Marketing Cloud, or is there a way to setup an automation to automatically opt contacts into a keyword without the need of using APIs for eg. SQL/Automation?

You can use automation to opt in the contacts using the MobileConnect keyword.
Below are the steps to follow:

First, create a data extension to store the subscriber details. This data extension should include fields such as ContactKey, MobileNumber, and Locale.

Create an import activity in Automation Studio to import the data from the data extension into MobileConnect. This activity will map the fields from your data extension to the required fields in MobileConnect.

Set up an automation in Automation Studio that includes the following steps:
Import Activity: Imports the filtered contacts into MobileConnect and opts them into the desired keyword.

Schedule the automation as per your requirement


